# SQL table and attribute design

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: One Transaction can have many Trans_Detail]

Reletionship : One Transaction can have many Trans_Detail
Trans_Detail is use to save the detail of the transaction,
such as the goods of guest taken from the hotel and the prices

Trans_Detail is use to record the transaction detail,
Trans_Detail.Trans_ID is PK also and is also FK,
can the database to be design like this?
or have any better suggestion?

Comment: Can it be designed like this - yes. Is it appropriate for your usage, given this level of detail we have no idea!

Comment: Trans_ID as varchar(10) and Primary key / Foreign Key is not a good idea. 
I would make a column `ID BIGINT INDENTITY(1,1)` in Transaction Table.
Then unique clustered index on ID, unique nonclustered index on Trans_ID. Change Trans_ID in Trans_Detail to BIGINT and reference it to Transaction.ID.....

Comment: It depends. It depends on what you are trying to achieve, what you want to store, what your business problem is, what your storage capacity is, how 'hot' you think the table access will be, whether this will be a table used for reporting.... so many questions, yet such a sparse question. Please supply more information about your scenario.

Comment: this is a part of hotel system database, my teacher said that this part is not a good database design, and said that it cannot be like this, because Trans_Detail.Trans_ID is set as PK and FK, but he cannnot tell us why it cannot to be like this and  no give us suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

A primary key must be unique. If trans_detail can have many rows for a given transaction ID, that transaction ID cannot be unique.

It looks like trans_detail contains the lines that make up the transaction, and that a transaction is more like an order.

If that's the case, you might want to rename trans_detail to "trans_line". The primary key can either be an artificial key (an auto increment number or something), or if the sequence of orderlines is important, you might include that as a field in trans_line, and make a compound primary key between trans_id and sequence.

I'm not a huge fan of abbreviations in table and column names - the extra typing is worth the clarity...